# Delphi: Make an .dll export a method that is declared via the type keyword

Tags: delphi

I have a library L in written in Delphi which uses method M. Program P uses method M of library L.

L looks kinda like this:

```
library L;

// uses and stuff ...

function M(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
begin
    Result := i*k;
end;

exports
    M;

begin
end.
```

P Looks kinda like this:

```
// uses and begin and class and stuff ...

type
  TTheMethod = function(i: Integer; k: Ineteger): Integer stdcall;

var
    hLib: THandle;
    methodVar: TTheMethod; 
    a: Iteger;
begin
    hLib := LoadLibrary(PWideChar('someFile.dll'));
    methodVar:= GetProcAddress(hLib, 'M');
    a := methodVar(2, 21);
```

If I would change my library so that M expects 3 integers then program P would still compile. Delphi doesn't know that M and methodVar neet to have the same type. I want my compiler to fail if only one of M and methodVar has changed type.

I tried to change the library to:

```
function _M(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
begin
    Result := i*k;
end;

var
    M: TTheMethodA = _M;

exports
   M;
```

But that won't compile.

Can I somehow get the compiler to check the types for me?

Comment: As David Heffernan said: seems impossible what I want to do. My workaround is that I collect all parameter for methond M in a record and use that record type in both library and program for typechecking.

Comment: Of course the compiler can't check that the two records match. You'll counter that the record is declared in a unit shared both modules. Which is fine so long as both modules were compiled with the same version of that shared unit. Ultimately there's no failsafe way for the compiler to save you from every imaginable mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I somehow get the compiler to check the types for me?

No you cannot. The compiler is simply incapable of validating the signature of external functions. Indeed, functions exported from a DLL do not contain any metadata to identify their signature.

The closest that you ever get to this is C++ name mangling which encodes the signature of the function in its decorated name. However, that's of no use to you because Delphi does not have any name mangling capabilities.

---

As for your code, you cannot export a variable of procedural type. You have to export an actual function. You could write your final piece of code like this:

```
function _M(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
begin
  Result := i*k;
end;

function M(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
begin
  Result := _M(i, k);
end;

exports
   M;
```

Or if you want the flexibility of routing via a variable then you would do it in a similar manner:

```
var
  _M: function(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
  // something must assign to _M at some point!

function M(i: Integer; k: Integer): Integer stdcall;
begin
  Result := _M(i, k);
end;

exports
   M;
```

Comment: I don't neccessay need the compiler to check the type signature of the exported symbol of the generated object code. I want it to check the type based on the source code and the method type I declared in it.

Comment: The compiler will check the source code that it can see. The compiler can check the exporting code when it compiles the DLL. The compiler can check the importing code when it compiles the EXE. But there are two separate compilation steps and in neither step can the compiler see what's over the other side of the interop boundary.

Comment: The compiler can see the source code in both compilation steps. The type TTheMethodA is a type declared in source code available in both comp. I don't need a way to check types of compiler generated symbols. I need a way to declare global methods using the type keyword.

Comment: *I need a way to declare global methods using the type keyword.* You cannot do that. `type` is used to declare types. You can only exports functions, you cannot export procedural variables. My update shows you how to export a function that in turn delegates to a procedural variable.

Comment: _My update shows you how to export a function that in turn delegates to a procedural variable._ Ok. But by doing this I can still change the type singnature in the library and the porgram will compile without errors.

Comment: @user3331950 I'm afraid that you are going to have to accept that the compiler can't check that for you. That is one of the hazards of this kind of interop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. `GetProcAddress` gives you only a pointer to the procedure entry without any additional information how exactly it should be called, how many parameters it expects, how and in which order arguments should be passed. Even C++ name mangling, would not help you there, because after all - it just a mangled name, nothing prevents you from passing wrong count of arguments to the method (its simple pointer cast after all). Maximum that you could achieve with it - `GetProcAddress` would fail to locate changed procedure, because it mangled name would be different. But still it is a runtime check instead of compile time validation.

Comment: I don't neccessay need the compiler to check the type signature of the exported symbol of the generated object code. I want it to check the type based on the source code and the method type I declared in it

Comment: Yes. But compiler could not understand that your dll method is linked to pointer, which you are trying to obtain using `GetProcAddress` method call.